# Requesting access token gives Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.RequestFailedException error

Tags: sharepoint-addin, azure, oauth

I'm trying to get a basic provider-hosted app up and running on Azure Websites. The app seems to work fine when testing locally with IIS Express, but when I deploy to Azure Websites and run the same request there I get the following error message in return:

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Token request failed.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.RequestFailedException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)
   at MyApp.TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(String targetPrincipalName, String targetHost, String targetRealm)
   at MyAppWeb.DataBackend.ClientContextFactory.NewClientContext()
   at MyAppWeb.Controllers.TimesheetNewEntryController.GetTimesheetNewEntry(Int32 employeeID, DateTime basisMonth)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass10.&lt;GetExecutor&gt;b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.&lt;TraceBeginEndAsyncCore&gt;d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.&lt;InvokeActionAsyncCore&gt;d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.&lt;TraceBeginEndAsyncCore&gt;d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.&lt;ExecuteAsyncCore&gt;d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.&lt;TraceBeginEndAsyncCore&gt;d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.&lt;SendAsync&gt;d__1.MoveNext()</StackTrace><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2WebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)</StackTrace></InnerException></Error>
```

I've tried creating a new app principal via AppRegNew.aspx, and inserting the new client ID and secret in the relevant place in the project's Web.config, but get the same error. Since I'm new to Sharepoint, I'm somewhat at loss to pin down what I could be missing here. Any help appreciated - thanks.